# WPF - Clear all textboxes in All TabItem of TabControl

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I use tabcontrol have tabitems to create new Dynamic content. I have button Reset to clear all textboxes in All TabItems. My code is working with tab focus. But, When I click the other tab and click again old tab, The content show again. Please help me so that I can clear all textboxes in all tabItems
My Code here:

```
        private void ClearControls(DependencyObject root)
    {

        System.Windows.Controls.TabControl controls = new System.Windows.Controls.TabControl();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); i++)
        {
            var control = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);

            if (control is System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)
            {

                (control as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox).Text = String.Empty;
            }
            else if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control) > 0)
            {
                ClearControls(control);
            }
        }
    }

    private void BtnResetTurnbyTurn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ClearControls(this);                    


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't waste your time with tree visualizer

Design your ui in a separately usercontrol and give  a name then from

Then head to your main window and give the area that is supposed to display the ui a name or just declare a grid and give it a name

Now head to your tabs and double click the one that is suppoused to show the ui you want and from the code just write the following

Just to clarify the names

I have my separately designd ui in a file called pages and it's name is myui and my usercontrol tag is name child

My viewing area is filled with a grid named 
Mainview

I have double clicked the required tab and it drove me to the cs file inside the click event

My code is

`  pages.myui mu =new pages.myui();

Mainview.Children.Clear();

Mainview.Cildren.Add(mu.child);`

It might be the most basic way to accomplish the mission but believe me it is a life saver

Comment for any question

I hope i have helped you
Yusuf naeem

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Well Welcome ;)